# ASP.Net jQuery dialog only shows up the first time it's hovered over

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a User Control which has an UpdatePanel, inside of which is a Repeater, inside of which are Linkbuttons:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RelatedEntityControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.Controls.Layout.RelatedURLControl" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="RelatedObjectsPanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function openPopup(url, h, w, t, link) {
            {
                if (url != null && h != null && w != null && t != null && link != null) {
                    var btn = document.getElementById(link);
                    var top_distance = btn.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    var left_distance = btn.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                    var myDialogX = left_distance - w/2;
                    var myDialogY = top_distance;
                    $('#PreviewWindow').html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " width="100%" height ="100%" src="' + url + '"> </iframe>');
                    $("#PreviewWindow").dialog({
                        title: t,
                        modal: false,
                        autoOpen: true,
                        height: h,
                        width: w,
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        position: [myDialogX, myDialogY],
                        dialogClass: 'dialog_fixed,ui-widget-header',
                        open: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden'); //this line does the actual hiding of the vertical scrollbar
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var btn = $('.previewLink');
            btn.hoverIntent(function (e) {
                e.target.click();
            }, function () { });
        });
    </script>

        <asp:Panel ID="URLPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="URLsCollapsiblePanel" runat="server" CollapseControlID="URLsLabel" ExpandControlID="URLsLabel" TargetControlID="URLsPanel" TextLabelID="URLsLabel"
            CollapsedText="[ + ]  Related URLs" ExpandedText="[ - ]  Related URLs" />
        <asp:Label ID="URLsLabel" runat="server" CssClass="collapsiblePanelHeader" Text="" Width="90%"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Panel ID="URLsPanel" runat="server" CssClass="collapsiblePanelContent" style="height: auto;">

            <asp:Repeater ID="URLsLocalRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="LocalRepeater_ItemDataBound" ItemType="SSPS.Models.Relationships.RelatedURL">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%# Item.Title %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Item.ActualLink %>' runat="server" Target="_blank" ToolTip='<%# Item.ToolTip %>'></asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="PreviewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="preview" OnClick="PreviewButton_Click" Font-Size="X-Small"  CssClass="previewLink"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <div id="PreviewWindow"></div>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel> 
</ContentTemplate>
```

The Javascript snippet attaches a hoverIntent function to the LinkButtons so that when the user hovers over them, I catch that hover, then cause the LinkButton to click().  From there we go server-side where I do some processing for the Linkbutton and eventually end up doing this to the LinkButton:

```
protected void PreviewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //figure out the loc, url and so forth
    string loc = ResolveUrl("~/PreviewWindow.aspx");
    loc += "?url=" + url.ActualLink;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "dlg", "openPopup('" + loc + "', " + url.HintHeight + ", " + url.HintWidth + ", '" + url.Title + "', '" + previewButton.ClientID + "')", true);
    return;
}
```

Now, I load my page, with its associated UserControl, and my LinkButtons just sit there staring at me until I hover over them.  Once I do that, then up pops the jQuery dialog and shows me the url I asked for.

All is well so far.  But once I close the dialog, everything breaks down.  I hover over a LinkButton again (same or different one, doesn't matter) and nothing happens.  The server-side PreviewButton_Click() function never gets called, and everything just sits there stupidly and stares at me.

To try to narrow down the problem, I removed the Javascript that sets up the hoverintent function.  Without that I have to actually click on the LinkButton, but that never fails to bring up the dialog, no matter how many times I click it, so it seems that there's a problem in the javascript portion.

I, with my not-exceedingly-in-depth knowledge of javascript, am thinking that there is some action that is messing up the javascript.  But I'm not sure where to look.  I've looked at it in Chrome's inspect window, but there doesn't seem to be any errors in the javascript.

Any suggestions?

Update: After trying suggesting from @mjw and @WevDev, I'm seeing even more evidence of strange behavior.  I found that anything I do in that UserControl that causes a postback will kill the jquery dialog.  So it looks indeed like the postback is causing a loss of the javascript that calls the hoverIntent.  But nothing I try will fix that loss of the javascript.

Comment: Move your script block down below your Panels. If you add an alert in that script block (hoverIntent) does it get fired after the first dialog is shown and closed? Do you have any console messages, error or warning?

Comment: I tried moving the script, but no joy.  An alert added to the hoverintent script block doesn't fire after the first time.  I'm not seeing any pertinent console messages or errors or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has an issue because

1. ASP.Net page lifecicle.

First hover works because you register hover event handler with this js code

```
$(function () {
   var btn = $('.previewLink');
   btn.hoverIntent(function (e) {
      e.target.click();
   }, function () { });
});
```

After postback ASP.NET rerenders everything inside updatepanel, so previously registered handlers are not valid anymore. It means that `var btn = $('.previewLink')` (previously selected elements) have nothing to do with newly rendered elements.

It is the same as if you have `<a>` which has a click handler, then you remove `<a>` and create new `<a>`. HTML will look as was before but click handler won't work anymore, because it has nothing to do with newly created element.

2. `$(function(){ .... });` this is a shorthand for document ready. So it fires only once when document is ready. After your postback this function doesn't get triggered. Hence you have newly created `<a>` but there is no js code to register handlers.

So, move script block down below panels (but keep inside updatepanel), and remove document ready shorthand. e.g.

```
<script>
............
var btn = $('.previewLink');
btn.hoverIntent(function (e) {
   e.target.click();
}, function () { });
</script>
```

Hope this helps

[UPDATE]

Try this:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var script = @"
        var btn = $('.previewLink');
                btn.hoverIntent(function (e) {
                    e.target.click();
                }, function () { });
        ";

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "someKey",
            script, true);
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to make any difference.  After the first dialog shows up and is dismissed, the click event isn't generated any more.  Or at least my breakpoint inside the Click handler isn't being hit.  And no more dialogs show up.

I have another button that, when hovered over, just generates an Alert() message.  That works just fine, until I trigger the jQuery dialog, then it starts failing to do the Alert.

Comment: Interestingly, and potentially helpfully, if I add a close: event to the jQuery dialog like this:

    close: function () { __doPostBack();}

then when the user closes the dialog, the page reloads and everything works correctly again.

Comment: Because entire page is loaded again and event handlers are registered. I did an update,  try it please.

Comment: Sweet cracker sandwich!  That last update did it.  Everything now works as expected--the hoverintent pops up my dialog for each link every time, I don't have to reload the page afterward.
Thanks a billion for your help!